# Unable to connect MariaDB 10.3 remotely on CentOS 7.6

Tags: mysql, linux, mariadb, centos7

I am trying to connect MariaDB 10.3(installed on CentOS 7.6) from remote machine, but I am not able connect.

`Output of grep`

[image]

Also I am unable to find .cnf file.

`Output of cd /etc --> ls`

[image]
Can anyone help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Is the mysql account you are using setup to accept remote connections?

Comment: Yes, I have created a user as: CREATE USER 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'pwd';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'user'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Answer (score 0):

## my.cnf (my.ini on windows)

-> Replace the IP Address with yours

```
bind-address        = 123.456.789.10
```

## then

```
CREATE USER 'myuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
CREATE USER 'myuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
```

## Last

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'%';
```

## Also check your iptables and firewalld

```
systemctl status firewalld
systemctl status iptables

iptables -L
firewall-cmd --list-all-zones
```